# Error by clicking on headers Datagrid WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, code-behind

I have a code behind in my XAML : when a condition is checked the targets rows will be Orange.

This is the result : 
[image]

This is  the code behind in XAML.cs:

```
     private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TrainOrdersClass item in dgBaseProd.ItemsSource)
        {
            var row = dgBaseProd.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
            if ((item.IsOverFilled == true) || (item.IsOverWeighed == true))
            {
                row.Background = Brushes.Orange;
            }
        }
    }
```

the problem is that when i click on the headers of DataGrid, all the colors is disappeared !

The Xaml:

```
      <DataGrid   Name="DataGrid"   AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
              Height="Auto" Width="780" Margin="10,10,10,10"
              IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PreloadedRailcarstList}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=BaseProductToUpdate}"
              AlternationCount="2"  AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" Loaded="DataGrid_Loaded"  >                                

                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OpenUpdateBaseProductViewCmd , RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding BaseProductToUpdate.name}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewKeyDown">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OpenUpdateBaseProductViewCmd , RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding BaseProductToUpdate.name}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>

            //..
```

How can I fix it ?
thanks,

Comment: Why dont you post some code?

Comment: Sorry , the code is all correct , for that i didn't post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `RowStyle` where you set the `Background` using `DataTriggers`:

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
              Height="Auto" Width="780" Margin="10,10,10,10"
              IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PreloadedRailcarstList}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=BaseProductToUpdate}"
              AlternationCount="2" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOverFilled}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOverWeighed}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OpenUpdateBaseProductViewCmd , RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding BaseProductToUpdate.name}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewKeyDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OpenUpdateBaseProductViewCmd , RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding BaseProductToUpdate.name}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

Don't use code-behind.

Comment: Thanks for your help,
but I have a problem : if I have 3 rows to be colored..
* When I use the code behind : always is true :the 3 rows are colored
* when I use the  DataTriggers in Xaml , sometimes I have 2, sometimes 3..it is not stable 

thanks,

Comment: Using data triggers are way more stable than using code-behind. Make sure that you have spelled the property names in the XAML correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, 
I made a mistake..it is correct now without code-behind
very thanks,